# Padding filename with Zeros for Integers with decimals

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

May someone help me with this issue I'm having with a Photoshop script for file naming?

What I am trying to do is add padding zeros to my filename that has whole numbers and decimals. This is what I have so far:

```
//Add leading zeros
function zeroPad(num) {
    var tmp = num.toString();
    while (tmp.length < 3) {tmp = '0' + tmp;}
    return tmp;
}
```

The problem is that this only works for files that only have whole numbers. If my filename has a decimal, it would just ignore it all together.

EX: With this script: doc36.jpg > doc036.jpg, but doc40.560.jpg > doc40.560.jpg

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: It won’t pad that second number because its `length` is > 3... what is your expected result?

Comment: well, because I'm averaging the images and is naming the file using the HSB brightness scale, my files name could look like this: 50.jpg, 19.57.jpg or 119.004.jpg. So I'm looking for something more cohesive (for file sorting purposes) and want to pad the number with zeros. Instead of naming the files like above, I want it to be 050.jpg, 009.57.jpg. The last would be ignored because it already has three integers before the decimals.

Comment: Also, when I changed it to 6, all it did was add more zeros to the file instead. So instead of 050.jpg, it'll give me 000050.jpg and continued to ignore the ones with decimals.

Comment: I see, so you want to keep the integer part always at X length, regardless of the decimals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pad only the integer portion of the number to get your expected result. So, check if it has a dot, if it does, split it and only pad the first part. If it doesn't, pad the whole number:

```js
function zeroPad(num) {
    var stringRep = num.toString();
    if (stringRep.indexOf(".") !== -1) {
        var tmp = stringRep.split(".");
        while (tmp[0].length < 3) {tmp[0] = '0' + tmp[0];}
        return tmp[0]+"."+tmp[1];
    }
    else {
        while (stringRep.length < 3) {stringRep = '0' + stringRep;}
        return stringRep;
    }
}
console.log(zeroPad(10));
console.log(zeroPad(1.3));
console.log(zeroPad(110));
console.log(zeroPad(10.4));
console.log(zeroPad(11234.4));
```

Comment: The functions works! Thank you so much. The only problem is that it only requires the function and not the console parts of it, so I deleted that because photoshop would not work with it in the code. Again, thank you so much. :D

Comment: Great! Yeah, the `console.log()` statements were there only as a demonstration. It's ok to take them off. I think the function can be a lot cleaner and "prettier" so keep working on it :)